# document ready with ui Dilaog

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok i have one page wich loads, with UI dialog one without. Problem is cuz i use document ready with keyup. In dialog keyup fires twice, and on page with out dialog normal once. If i remove document ready keyup function wont work, on page with out dialog

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    is_draft_started = 0;

    $(":input").keyup(function() {
        alert(33232);
        if(is_draft_started == 0) {
            s2 = setInterval('draft("' + frm_name + '")', auto_save_time);
            is_draft_started = 1;

    });

});
```

Is it a way to solve this, if this code is in dialog it auto add one more document ready so key up fires twice

Comment: could try `$(":input").off("keyup").keyup(...` this will remove any keyup listener if there is one

Comment: i came up with this  $(":input").keyup(function(e) {
                    
                $( ":input" ).unbind("keyup").bind( "keyup", function() {
                   alert(33232);
   if(is_draft_started == 0) {
    s2 = setInterval('draft("' + frm_name + '")', auto_save_time);
    is_draft_started = 1;
   }
  });
 }); but this close keyup wont fire on first keyp

Answer (score 0):

My concern here is that everytime the KeyUp Event fires,
You are binding a setInterval to execute every X seconds
So Eventually as Keyup is supposed to fire multiple times you will have generated a dozen calls to your backend for saving a draft ...

Are you sure the event is firing twice and not bubbling ??

you should pass the event variable in your function and use
event.bubbles = false;
AND
event.stopPropagation() to stop further propagation.

Comment: this `if(is_draft_started == 0)` prevent the bind of the `setInterval`

Comment: @Hacketo will it prevent it only the first time or everytime ? if i enter "abcd" in the textbox keyup should fire atleast 4 times ... ?

Comment: $(":input").keyup(function(e) {
                    
                $( ":input" ).unbind("keyup").bind( "keyup", function() {
                   alert(33232);
   if(is_draft_started == 0) {
    s2 = setInterval('draft("' + frm_name + '")', auto_save_time);
    is_draft_started = 1;
   }
  });
 }); i came up with this solution its close but keyup wont fire on first, later work how it should

Comment: @Aukhan, yes keyup will fire 4 times, but the first time `is_draft_started` is set to 1. So it will prevent binding after the first.